# ElasticSearch nested object that contains array of integers

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Here is a schema with a nested property one of the properties of which (`AncestorIds`) is an array of integers.

```
{
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties" : {
        "Id" : {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Name" : {
            "type": "text",
            "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_alphanumeric"
                },
                "text" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "analyzer": "english"
                }
            }
        },
        "Menus" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                "Id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                },
                "Name" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_alphanumeric"
                },
                "AncestorsIds" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a document.

```
{
        "Id": 12781279,
        "Name": "Thing of purpose made to fit",
        "Menus": [
            {
                "Id": -571057,
                "Name": "Top level menu",
                "AncestorsIds": [
                    -571057
                ]
            }
            ,
            {
                "Id": 1022313,
                "Name": "Other",
                "AncestorsIds": [
                    -571057
                    ,
                    1022313
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

In the supplier's catalogue a product can be in more than location in their menu heirarchy and therefore `Menus` is an array.

The UI shows a tree for the menus and for each entry (not just the leaves) in the tree I need to get the number of matching documents from the search. For the menu item whose id is *z* this is the number of matching documents that have *z* in the `Menus.AncestorIds` array in any of the objects in their `Menus` array.

Is this possible?

I've got this, but changing `Menus.Id` to `Menus.AncestorIds` doesn't work.

```
"aggs":{
    "menus": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Menus"
      },
      "aggs":{
        "menu_aggregation": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "Menus.Id",
          "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit.
So if the search results contained these two documents:

```
[
    {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Thing of purpose made to fit",
            "Menus": [
                {"Id": 10, "Name": "Top level menu", "AncestorsIds": [10]},
                {"Id": 12, "Name": "Top level menu", "AncestorsIds": [10, 11, 12]}
            ]
    },
    {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Thing of purpose made to fit differently",
            "Menus": [
                {"Id": 10, "Name": "Top level menu", "AncestorsIds": [10]},
                {"Id": 13, "Name": "Top level menu", "AncestorsIds": [10, 11, 13]}
            ]
    }
]
```

Menu 10 is the root that has child 11 that has children 12 and 13.

Then for each menu item I want to know the number of results at or under it.
(And a menu item has results if and only if it appears in an `AncestorIds` array of at least one search result.)

```
Menu Count
10   2
11   2
12   1
13   1
```

Comment: Hi @Richard can you please specify your expected output in json-like format ? Would be very helpful :)

Comment: The answer appears to be to change the schema so that it can be queried as required -- which seems somewhat unsatisfactory.